# Is it possible to recover deleted Jobspec script?

Tags: palantir-foundry

Is there any way to recover the file Jobspec that was once deleted? Or...I'm thinking of versions of Jobspec being tracked somewhere that's accessible by superuser?

TIA.

Some sources say that super user can manually edit Jobspec. Thinking it'd be the same for recovering deleted Jobspec file/script?

Comment: AFAIK, you can only manually edit jobspecs of workerType 'magritte-task'. As to where to find previous jobspecs, depending on your transaction retention policy, you could try checking out build history. Each entry has field "jobspec" which keeps the record for that particular build.

Comment: Why do you need to recover a jobspec? can't you just roll back your authoring repo to point to the commit that generated the jobspec you want?